# Update json using sed - Docker container

Tags: sed

Working with docker and looking to update JSON with sed.

**Here is the JSON :**

```
var configLocalnet = {
  version: '20180720',
  websocket: {
    protocol: 'http',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8082',
  },
  publicapi: {
    protocol: 'http',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8082',
  },
}

var configMainnet = {
  version: '20180720',
  websocket: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'to_update',
    port: '443',
  },
  publicapi: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'to_update',
    port: '443',
  },
}
module.exports = process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT === "mainnet" ? configMainnet : configLocalnet;
```

**Need to the values in config **var configMainnet** to change to:**

Both host details inside configMainnet should be changed to test.test.io

```
var configMainnet = {
  version: '20180720',
  websocket: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'test.test.io',
    port: '443',
  },
  publicapi: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'test.test.io',
    port: '443',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
sed -E "s/(host:.).+$/\1'test.test.io',/g"
```

---

Example:

```
echo "var configMainnet = {
  version: '20180720',
  websocket: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'to_update',
    port: '443',
  },
  publicapi: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'to_update',
    port: '443',
  },
}" | sed -E "s/(host:.).+$/\1'test.test.io',/g"
var configMainnet = {
  version: '20180720',
  websocket: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'test.test.io',
    port: '443',
  },
  publicapi: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: 'test.test.io',
    port: '443',
  },
}
```